# SSL termination in HAProxy with .cer and .key files

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I am trying to convert my `nginx` config to `haproxy` config. I am having trouble using same cert pair in `haproxy`.

In `nginx` i defined something like this.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
```

Is there any way to achieve this in `haproxy` ?

I can convert `.cer` and `.key` files to `.pem` and use it in `haproxy` but want to use .cer and .key files only.